# Why are we mapping properties with different names when logging in Spring Boot?

Tags: logging, spring-boot

This is with reference to [Spring Boot - Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging) documentation. Why are we mapping the property *logging.path* to logger variable *LOG_PATH* and  *logging.file* to logger variable *LOG_FILE*?

This actually leads to confusion to developers who see one variable name while defining it and another name while consuming it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're asking.  Are you trying to make a comment to the *developers* about why they did it like that, or are you asking how you can leverage it?

Comment: I'm trying to find the reasoning behind the property pairs. Why has it been done like that, why not directly use "logging.path" / "logging.file" directly in log configs, instead of mapping them to upper case properties "LOG_PATH" and "LOG_FILE" respectively.

Comment: I'm trying to find the reasoning behind the property pairs. Why has it been done like that, why not directly use "logging.path" / "logging.file" directly in log configs, instead of mapping them to upper case properties "LOG_PATH" and "LOG_FILE" respectively.

Comment: Oh.  That's what I suspected.  Well, we're not the devs.  You may have better luck on their GitHub page for it.

Comment: Raised an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9644) and was asked to move back to stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Since not all properties from Spring's `Environment` abstraction are available in the logging system we needed to adapt them. It's pretty common for logging libraries to support [references to environment variables](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) so that's the approach that we took.

It's common to see logging configuration like this in a standard logback file:

```
<file>${USER_HOME}/myApp.log</file>
```

So it felt pretty natural to add [Spring Boot specific variables](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration) in the same format.

I also personally quite like the fact that there's a difference between the keys in the `application.properties` file and the ones you can use in your logging configuration. I think it helps to enforce that you can just add new entries to your `application.properties` and expect use them in your logging configuration.